# Combining a Vector and a dataframe

Tags: r

I have 1 data frame with a list of countries and their country code. I'd like to be able to in R to create a country-year file for a given range of years.

So the dataframe with countries looks like

Code Country 
2     United States
20    Canada
31    Bahamas

And I'd like

Code   Country         Year
2     United States   1945
2     United States   1946
2     United States   1947
2     United States   1948
20     Canada         1945
20     Canada         1946
20     Canada         1947
20     Canada         1948

Its such a simple question - but I've spent an hour without any luck, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably looking for `merge`. But your question is unclear and incomplete. Where do the years come from? Surely they are in some other variable? What is it?

Comment: I spent a lot of time looking at the merge function - but it looks like you have to have common variables in each set of data to merge. The years are from 1945-2005 - I'm really just looking to make a template of country-years for this time period that I can use to build an original data set. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text="Code Country
2 'United States'
20 'Canada'
31 'Bahamas'", header=T)

year   <- 1945:2005
len    <- length(year)
code   <- rep(df$Code,    each=len)
ctry   <- rep(df$Country, each=len)
dframe <- data.frame(code=code, country=ctry, year=year)
rm(code, year, len, ctry, df)
dframe
```

Comment: Let me know if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: Thank you! I'm so new to this - I'm trying to parse out what you did. Any chance you could explain what the lines of code with rep in it are doing?

Comment: You're welcome, @user2980707. It's hard when you're getting started. The relevant documentation is here: [?rep](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html). It stands for "replicate", and it means that it will create a vector for you where the input elements (eg, `df$Code` is `2 20 31`) are repeated over & over. There are 2 ways it can be done: if you use the `times` argument, the whole vector will be concatenated (eg, `2 20 31 2 20 31` etc); if you use the `each` argument, the 1st element will be repeated some number of times, then the 2nd etc (eg, `2 2 2 ... 20 20 ...`).

Answer (score 0):

The merge variable can you what you are after (I think anyway) have a look at the code below and see if it does what you are after.

```
# replicate data
countries <- c(rep("United States",4),rep("Canada",4))
dates <- c("1945","1946","1947","1948","1945","1946","1947","1948")

dates.country <- as.data.frame(cbind(countries,dates))

code.country <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("2","United States","20","Canada","31","Bahamas"),ncol=2, byrow = TRUE))

# set names for code.country
# variables to be merge on variable names must match

names(code.country) <- c("code","countries")

# this form of merge replicates what you want
combined.country <- merge(dates.country,code.country)

# there are a lot of options for merge so it is worth looking at
# ?merge to get and idea of what it can do. For example adding the 
# all=TRUE flag will mean that all data is represented even if it
# is only in one dataset

combined.country.all <- merge(dates.country,code.country, all=TRUE)
```